# Wordpress URL Parameters

Tags: wordpress

I have a 'Portfolio' page in Wordpress, that uses it's own custom Portfolio template.  It displays all Categories currently.

What I want to happens is, when a user clicks on a Category link, I want it to display the same page, but with the Categories narrowed down, based on what the user clicked.  I want it stay on the Portfolio page though...so the url would still be http://www.site.com/portfolio, or http://www.site.com/portfolio/the-category-they-clicked

Whats the best way to do this?  If I pass the Category in url like above, will it still go to the Portfolio template?  And do I access that Category param with $_GET?  Or is there a more 'Wordpress' way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for doing this, you can have a category.php in your themes folder, which is the copy of portfolio-template, except that the query is modified to display the narrowed down results.

But I'm guessing you want something more elegant, so I suggest filtering categories using a jquery plugin like [isotop](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) you can see an example of this done [here](http://pepde.com/portfolio-page/) - Hope that helped.